# How to prevent suspended Google account to signup

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am integrating ASP.NET application using Google Drive API. For this after authentication we re uploading Files to Google drive. I am using Google client library to Call the APIs.

Everything is working as expected I am able to authenticate user successfully and able to upload the file successfully.

In one scenario when the user Google account is suspended then I am getting refresh token from Google but my upload method is failing and it is not uploading the file to Google drive.

I want to restrict the user on Signup screen itself, when account is suspended.

What parameter do I have to pass to achieve this please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this info is not easily available. You have two options :

1. Use the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) to see if the user is suspended. This requires additional OAuth permissions to be provided by an admin of the domain.
2. At login, try and perform a Drive API call to see if you get an error or not. If you get an error (with a couple of retried) and the error message matches the one you had for suspended users, then you can deny access to the user.

Comment: You wouldn't know what the exact error message the API will return if the user has a suspended account? I am wondering if this is something that can be tested for. With out neededing to add the Directory API.

Comment: And you CAN test it, that's exactly my point in option number 2

Comment: Google API is not returning any error it returns null object if upload fails. On another note If I am not doing any Drive operation and based on Google Authentication I want to allow him to login into our site then I can't perform drive operation because for Signing into our site we have only basic scopes to read user information not drive scope is mentioned. Then how we can prevent suspended google account on signup. Like when we try to signup on Google site it redirect us to an error page.